# How to customize a admin menu in Magento

Tags: magento

I just created a module Custoreport and this is custoreport xml configuration.

```
<adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <custoreport>
                <title>Custoreport</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <admin2_adminhtml_custoreport>
                        <title>Manage Custoreport</title>
                        <action>admin2/adminhtml_custoreport</action>
                    </admin2_adminhtml_custoreport>                    
                </children>
            </custoreport>
        </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

And the menu is "Custoreport/Manage Custoreport". Now, I want to customize this menu like "reports/customers/Manage Custoreport"

Please give me the way to make it.
Many thanks!

Comment: read this article http://codegento.com/2011/02/adding-a-new-admin-menu-item/

Answer (score 1):

Look at Reports module configuration (/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/etc/adminhtml.xml)

Code may be

```
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <report>
                <children>
                    <customers>
                        <children>
                            <admin2_adminhtml_custoreport>
                                <title>Manage Custoreport</title>
                                <action>admin2/adminhtml_custoreport</action>
                            </admin2_adminhtml_custoreport>
                        </children>
                    </customers>
                </children>
            </report>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
```

Comment: @Юрий Николаев: How can I do: <action>`admin`/adminhtml_custoreport</action>?